# Simple UPDATE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple oracle statement, and I don't see why it won't work.

```
UPDATE sdg_user,sdg
SET sdg_user.U_START_DATE = trunc(sysdate-2,'DD')
WHERE sdg_user.SDG_ID = sdg.SDG_ID
and sdg.name in('875933','873401','875946','876036','876103','876271','876274','876297','876298')
```

Comment: my final goal is to set my U_START_DATE to sysdate-2 from SDG_USER

Comment: What is the error you are getting?